# Помогите советом, как с html и css сделать такие блоки?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

[image: как должно быть]
Все выполняю с помощью bootstrap. 
Нужно выполнить блоки в точности как на прилагаемом изображении.
Самые главные моменты:

1. чтобы изображение залезало на рамку
2. чтобы при наведении на блок, внизу появлялась полоса красная.Причем это полоса должна быть НЕ со скошенными краями, как если бы мы просто изменяли цвет нижнего бордера на красный.
3. и чтобы все было адаптивно и не сыпалось при изменении размера экрана.

Возможно есть какой-то простой способ реализации этой штуки. У меня пока все с жуткими костылями, и сыпется верстка. Испробовал уже самые разные вариации

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
section {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 64px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 3px solid silver;
  border-left: none;
}

section:hover {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG">
  <div>Тут какое-то описание</div>
</section>

<section>
  <img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG">
  <div>Тут какое-то описание</div>
</section>

<section>
  <img src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/cbfaff96665b7567defe1b34a883db8b?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG">
  <div>Тут какое-то описание</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо дружище. Я только не понял момента, как ты сделал что при ховере, не видна вся рамка, а только низ.

Comment: И еще при наведении остается нижняя серая рамка. Я ее делал transparent при наведении, а боковые края серой рамки остались скошенные.

Comment: Вроде решил. Добавил в div:hover нижняя рамка none. Вроде пока не прыгает ничего, и скос исчез)

Comment: Но ведь `box-sizing: content-box;` и так есть по-умолчанию.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, в принципе да, но это первое, что обычно переопределяют. Даже я, несмотря на то, что не люблю использовать reset.css, почти всегда переопределяю box-sizing :)

Answer (score 2):

Похоже на то, учитывая, что в при наведении серой рамки нет + появляется тень (судя по скриншоту).

```css
section {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 64px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: none;
  background-color: #fff;
}

section:hover {
  border-color: #7d2d3a;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.08);
}

section:hover div {
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <img src="http://f.mypage.ru/6e4af88cc78db945ebdc802cee4624da_42989cf41c481cf14353424ad0973e2e.jpg">
  <div>Куррорт-Аваза</div>
</section>

<section>
  <img src="http://toyrism.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Красивый-болгарский-курорт-Созополь-5.jpg">
  <div>Красивый болгарский курорт Созополь</div>
</section>

<section>
  <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3803/33188251585_155d17931a_o.jpg">
  <div>Hotel Splendid Conference Spa Resort 5* расположен в чудесном курортном местечке – Бечичи на берегу чистейшего Адриатического моря.</div>
</section>
```

---

А насчёт:

> Вроде решил. Добавил в div:hover нижняя рамка none. Вроде пока не прыгает ничего, и скос исчез)

то лучше использовать селектор:

```
section:hover div
```

чтобы при наведении и на пикчу срабатывало то же самое поведение.

---

Так же можно вместо красного бордера для `section` сделать изящнее, с анимацией через `section:after`.

Например https://jsfiddle.net/acid_grip/3u3pu41y/

Comment: Непонятно только зачем изначально нужна серая рамка %)

Comment: Спасибо Артем. Классно получилось с такой анимацией)